# How to invoke plugin from command line (sbt beginner)?

Tags: scala, command-line, sbt, scalafmt

Following https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html I'm trying to reformat my Scala code via command line.

How to execute the `scalafmt` command ?

Loading `sbt` from the project can I invoke `scalafmt` ?

Using below returns error :

```
sbt:skeleton> scalafmt
[error] Not a valid command: scalafmt (similar: last)
[error] Not a valid project ID: scalafmt
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: scalafmt (similar: scalaHome, scalaArtifacts, scalaInstance)
[error] scalafmt
[error]         ^
sbt:skeleton> my-project/scalafmt
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: scalafmt (similar: scalaHome, scalaArtifacts, scalaInstance)
[error] my-project/scalafmt
[error]                    ^
sbt:skeleton>
```

Comment: Could you check your project/plugins.sbt ? 
It should include 

```addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta"    % "sbt-scalafmt"        % "2.0.2")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would suggest checking your project/plugins.sbt if it includes

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-scalafmt" % scalaMetaVersion)
```

looks like it can't find `scalafmt` command.

Second run `sbt plugins`  to check if it's enabled - you should have something like this: `org.scalafmt.sbt.ScalafmtPlugin: enabled in skeleton`